# jQuery Complicated Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I'm 90% there. I have an accordion module that I'm trying to finish up, but there's one piece that eludes me.

Functionality (working)

- Accordion closed (default)
- User clicks the bottom bar ( the "+" symbol)
- Module opens
- Module Open

  - Top area changes to blue background
  - Icon in top area turns yellow
  - The "+" changes to "-"
- User clicks on another accordion module
- Closes the previously open module

Functionality (missing / not working as intended). When the user clicks the next module to open it up, the previously open on closes (working), however the classes are not being removed to make it go back to its default state.

I realize my jQ might not be the most optimized; so I appreciate any suggestions in that respect too.

```js
// jQuery Plugins
$(function(){
  "use strict";
  // Accordion Section
  $('.mod-accordion-bottom').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('.mod-accordion-top').removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('i.fa').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    $('.mod-accordion-content').slideUp();


    if( $(this).prev().is(':hidden') === true ) {
      $(this).prev().slideDown('normal');
      $(this).parent().find('.mod-accordion-top').addClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().find('i.fa').addClass('active');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.mod-accordion-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }

.mod-accordion-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  background: #282c2f; }
  .mod-accordion-top.open {
    background-color: #3d61a4; }
  .mod-accordion-top-title, .mod-accordion-top-image {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 10.3125rem; }
  .mod-accordion-top-title {
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-copy, .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
      width: 100%;
      float: left; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-top-title-copy, .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
          width: 48%; } }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
      margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
      padding: 0 155px 0 0; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
          border-right: 2px solid #fefefe; } }
    .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
      text-align: center; }
      .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa {
        margin-top: 50px; }
        .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa.active {
          color: #ffee00; }

.mod-accordion-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.625rem 0; }
  .mod-accordion-content-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0.625rem; }
    .mod-accordion-content-wrap:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
  .mod-accordion-content-title, .mod-accordion-content-copy {
    width: 100%; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
      .mod-accordion-content-title, .mod-accordion-content-copy {
        width: 50%;
        float: left; } }
  .mod-accordion-content-copy {
    padding: 25px 35px 25px 25px;
    background-color: #3d61a4;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 21.875rem; }
    .mod-accordion-content-copy h4, .mod-accordion-content-copy p {
      text-align: left; }
    .mod-accordion-content-copy a {
      color: #3d61a4;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      padding: 3px 0 0;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 40px auto 0;
      display: block;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
      .mod-accordion-content-copy a:hover {
        background-color: #faa74a;
        color: #fefefe; }
  .mod-accordion-content-title {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
      padding: 20px; }
      @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
        .mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
          margin: 20px;
          padding: 0; } }
    .mod-accordion-content-title img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: -1; }

.mod-accordion-bottom {
  background-color: #b4b6b7;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center; }
  .mod-accordion-bottom.active, .mod-accordion-bottom:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #3d61a4; }
  .mod-accordion-bottom i.fa {
    color: #3d61a4;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 8px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer; }
    .mod-accordion-bottom i.fa.fa-minus {
      color: #faa74a; }

#body-content {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  color: #fefefe; }
  #body-content p.lead {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.9375rem;
    color: #919dc9; }
/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d7ed46e5fb.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mod-accordion-wrap">
            <div class="mod-accordion-top">
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-title">
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-copy">
                  <h4>Lorem Ipsums' Story</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-icon show-for-medium">
                  <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-image">
                <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
              </div>
            </div><!-- END Top -->
            <div class="mod-accordion-content">
              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Precision</h2>
                  <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Precision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Engineering</h2>
                  <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Engineering Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Engineering Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Development</h2>
                  <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Development Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Development Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                  <h2>Future Vision</h2>
                  <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                  <h4>Main Future Vision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <h4>Second Future Vision Statement</h4>
                  <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- END Content -->
            <div class="mod-accordion-bottom">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </div> <!-- END Bottom -->
          </div> <!-- END Wrap -->

<div class="mod-accordion-wrap">
            <div class="mod-accordion-top">
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-title">
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-copy">
                  <h4>Our PoCT Story</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-icon show-for-medium">
                  <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mod-accordion-top-image">
                <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
              </div>
            </div><!-- END Top -->
            <div class="mod-accordion-content">
              <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
                <h2>Precision</h2>
                <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
                <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
                <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                <h4>Second Precision Statement</h4>
                <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div> <!-- END Content -->
            <div class="mod-accordion-bottom">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </div> <!-- END Bottom -->
          </div> <!-- END Wrap -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by adding the active class to the `wrap` element instead of adding it to each and every element. This will help us to simplify the script

```js
// jQuery Plugins
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  // Accordion Section
  $('.mod-accordion-bottom').click(function() {
    var $wrap = $(this).closest('.mod-accordion-wrap').toggleClass('active'),
      active = $wrap.hasClass('active');
    $wrap.find('.mod-accordion-bottom i').toggleClass('fa-minus', active).toggleClass('fa-plus', !active);
    $wrap.find('.mod-accordion-content')[active ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('normal');

    if (active) {
      var $other = $('.mod-accordion-wrap.active').not($wrap).removeClass('active');
      $other.find('.mod-accordion-content').slideUp();
      $other.find('.mod-accordion-bottom i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.mod-accordion-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
}
.mod-accordion-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  background: #282c2f;
}
.mod-accordion-top.open {
  background-color: #3d61a4;
}
.mod-accordion-top-title,
.mod-accordion-top-image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 10.3125rem;
}
.mod-accordion-top-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mod-accordion-top-title-copy,
.mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mod-accordion-top-title-copy,
  .mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
    width: 48%;
  }
}
.mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0 155px 0 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mod-accordion-top-title-copy {
    border-right: 2px solid #fefefe;
  }
}
.mod-accordion-top-title-icon {
  text-align: center;
}
.mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.mod-accordion-wrap.active .mod-accordion-top-title-icon i.fa {
  color: #ffee00;
}
.mod-accordion-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.625rem 0;
}
.mod-accordion-content-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
}
.mod-accordion-content-wrap:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mod-accordion-content-title,
.mod-accordion-content-copy {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mod-accordion-content-title,
  .mod-accordion-content-copy {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
}
.mod-accordion-content-copy {
  padding: 25px 35px 25px 25px;
  background-color: #3d61a4;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 21.875rem;
}
.mod-accordion-content-copy h4,
.mod-accordion-content-copy p {
  text-align: left;
}
.mod-accordion-content-copy a {
  color: #3d61a4;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 3px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.mod-accordion-content-copy a:hover {
  background-color: #faa74a;
  color: #fefefe;
}
.mod-accordion-content-title {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mod-accordion-content-title h2 {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
.mod-accordion-content-title img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.mod-accordion-bottom {
  background-color: #b4b6b7;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.mod-accordion-wrap.active .mod-accordion-bottom,
.mod-accordion-bottom:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3d61a4;
}
.mod-accordion-bottom i.fa {
  color: #3d61a4;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 8px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mod-accordion-bottom i.fa.fa-minus {
  color: #faa74a;
}
#body-content {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  color: #fefefe;
}
#body-content p.lead {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.9375rem;
  color: #919dc9;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d7ed46e5fb.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mod-accordion-wrap">
  <div class="mod-accordion-top">
    <div class="mod-accordion-top-title">
      <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-copy">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsums' Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-icon show-for-medium">
        <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mod-accordion-top-image">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Top -->
  <div class="mod-accordion-content">
    <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
        <h2>Precision</h2>
        <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
        <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <h4>Second Precision Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
        <h2>Engineering</h2>
        <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
        <h4>Main Engineering Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <h4>Second Engineering Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
        <h2>Development</h2>
        <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
        <h4>Main Development Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <h4>Second Development Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mod-accordion-content-wrap">
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
        <h2>Future Vision</h2>
        <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
        <h4>Main Future Vision Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <h4>Second Future Vision Statement</h4>
        <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Content -->
  <div class="mod-accordion-bottom">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- END Bottom -->
</div>
<!-- END Wrap -->

<div class="mod-accordion-wrap">
  <div class="mod-accordion-top">
    <div class="mod-accordion-top-title">
      <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-copy">
        <h4>Our PoCT Story</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="mod-accordion-top-title-icon show-for-medium">
        <i class="fa fa-book fa-3x"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mod-accordion-top-image">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Top -->
  <div class="mod-accordion-content">
    <div class="mod-accordion-content-title">
      <h2>Precision</h2>
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mod-accordion-content-copy">
      <h4>Main Precision Statement</h4>
      <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

      <h4>Second Precision Statement</h4>
      <p>Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page. Brief text about site section expanded within the landing page.</p>

      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END Content -->
  <div class="mod-accordion-bottom">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- END Bottom -->
</div>
<!-- END Wrap -->
```

Comment: This is a good solution - however it's swapping out the individual icons instead of preserving their icon state. There are unique icons for each module and some stay static

Comment: @SalB check the update, the icon filter is updated to `.mod-accordion-bottom i`

Comment: Thanks! I was heading that direction! Thanks for helping my simplify! :D I tend to over-think these things.

Comment: What would be the best way to toggle them the way I had? Where if you click on an inactive module, it will close the other one, but you can also close the same one you had open.